# How to get url of web app of other spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to get url of web app of other spreadsheet, so I can use that link to put in web app of the current spreadsheet. When open this web app we can click the link to go to other web app.
I don't want to put the link manually. I want to get web app url automatically from file that I set.

Normally we get url with

```
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

But that just get web app url from current file only. I want to get web app url from other file or spreadsheet. I also try to combine with

```
DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next();
```

But it's can't combine together with class ScriptApp.

---

Let me explain more about my project.
I have a lot of spreadsheet files and each file already deployed as web app.
Each spreadsheet has its own pair. Something like file name "ss1a" will be pair with file name "ss1b", and "ss2a" pair with "ss2b", etc.

My point is I want to write some code in "ss1a" to looking for file "ss1b" and get link web app url from that file automatically, so it can use that link send to html and post in web app of "ss1a", without doing anything anymore in "ss1b".

I don't have any problem with version deployment url because I separate file html as text file and let all spreadsheet do

```
HtmlService.createTemplate(DriveApp.getFilesByName("index.txt").next().getBlob());
```

to read html from that file.
So I have only one version of deployment.

I just want to use the same code in every spreadsheet files and let it detect automatically without copy paste any ID or do anything manually.

Please help me
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Get Deployement URL:

```
function getDeploymentUrl() {
  const scriptId = "your script id";
  const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
  const url1 = base + scriptId + "/deployments";
  const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
  const robj = JSON.parse(r);
  const deploymentId = robj.deployments[robj.deployments.length - 1].deploymentId;
  const deploymenturl = robj.deployments[robj.deployments.length - 1].entryPoints[robj.deployments[robj.deployments.length - 1].entryPoints.length - 1].webApp.url;
  return deploymenturl;
}
```

You can find the script id in the url of the editor and also in project settings.  This function is using the Apps Script API

Comment: I'm sorry I really have no idea about domain. I just using free google drive and google sheet to make web app only. And I don't think there is any domain in my web app url.

Comment: Try this version which uses the entryPoints.  You will still need to get the script id which is in the url of the editor